# Change database connection according to login in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Current i am trying create a SaaS software in Laravel 5.3.The current issue is i am unable to switch database according to the user login.
I want to achieve the following work flow .

1) User login with username,Password,and a database name - Finished
2)Need to fetch credentials according to the provided database name from master database - Finished
3)I Need to Switch the entire application connection to provided database name if database name is valid.

i already created a middleware for switching database as follows

```
class SetDb
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Session::has('DB_DATABASE')) {

        Config::set('database.connections.mysql7', array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST','127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT','3306'),
            'database' => Session::get('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => Session::get('DB_USER'),
            'password' => Session::get('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
        ));
        DB::reconnect('mysql7');
        dd(DB::reconnect('mysql7'));
    } else {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::flush(); 
        DB::reconnect('mysql');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

i hope someone is able to finished the task , Thanks in advance :)